# Bootstrap's dropdown menu is hidden by datatables

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

this question is asked many times but nothing is working for me, So I've added dropdown menu in table header it is hidden by table body. If I remove overflow from the class **"dataTables_scrollHead"** dropdown is showing but problem is when I scroll table body(x-axis),table header is fixed it's not moving along with table body content .Can anyone please suggest some answer.

**What I tried:**(removed overflow:hidden)

```
.table-scrollable { 
overflow-x: visible; 
overflow-y: visible;
```

}

Thank you

Comment: You should add some code to show what you have tried. Add an example, etc. Before posting a question, you should look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've edited my question,Can anyone help me in this